# Caching a mapping table in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching

Caching a mapping table which stores only mapping info of other tables.e.g I have a table which only stores the ids of table1, table2 and table3. I am doing batch operations on very large datasets and before making any DB inserts, doing a DB lookup to ensure the data does not exist but the records are very high and I want to reduce the number of db calls. How can I cache it , is it possible?